# Add HTML class/ID to Google Maps Marker (API V3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I add a class or ID to a Google Maps API V3 marker? I want to be able to access the markers using jQuery.

EDIT: Hi clarkf, thanks for the response. Using Firebug I'm not able to see those classes when inspecting my map but I did notice there are two divs. One for the icon and one for the button.

What I am trying to do is:
I have a list of lost pets displayed on the site, they are also displayed on the map. Each pet in the list has a unique ID, and I want the ones on the map to mirror this ID using a class as ID's need to be unique and there might be several points per pet. So I'm looking for a way of adding a class to a map marker. This way when a user selects a lost pet from the list it'll highlight it on the map or vice-versa.

Thanks

Ric

Comment: That sounds tricky. Why do you need to access them via jQuery? The API is pretty comprehensive, and should allow you to do most of the manipulation through it. **EDIT**: After a bit of poking and prodding, I discovered that map markers already have `id`s. Their `class` is `gmnoprint`, and their IDs are something in the pattern of `mtgt_#.####` (I found `mtgt_A.1000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not managed to get this to work. Not sure it's possible yet. I did hack around it though as my markers were stored in an array along with the item I wanted to link to them. So I could say if the first item was clicked, then highlight the marker for the first item of the array. A bit crude, and it'll break if a system needed several markers for one item but it works now. If you're wondering what I am talking about it's here: http://www.isabellevetslostpets.com/page/search-for-a-lost-pet

Search for lost pets and click a result (sadly no one is uploading photos!). The results are stored in the same array (a JSON object loaded via AJAX - Firebug it to see) as the marker info so that's how I tie them together.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of prodding, I discovered map markers all have the class of `gmnoprint` (assumed **G**oogle **M**aps **No** **Print**). So, I did a maps search for pizza near my house, and in a Chrome's Inspector's Console Window, I:

```
> var list = document.getElementsByClassName('gmnoprint');
  [...] //length=37
> for ( var i = 0, item; item = list[i]; i++ ) { console.log(item.id); }
  //(11 items with no id)
  mtgt_A.1001
  mtgt_B.1001
  mtgt_C.1001
  mtgt_D.1001
  mtgt_E.1001
  mtgt_F.1001
  mtgt_G.1001
  mtgt_H.1001
  mtgt_I.1001
  mtgt_J.1001
  mtgt_A.1000
  map_overview
  //Irrelevant information...
```

All of the visible markers were in the format of `mtgt_[LETTER].1001`. The numeral suffix seems to have something to do with multiple sets of lettered markers (`mtgt_A.1000` was a hidden marker - maybe the place wasn't open, or something. But all pertinent markers followed that schema. So, presumably, you should be able to access the markers via jQuery with `$('#mtgt_[LETTER].1001')` - again, depending on your context, but maybe what you're looking for is

```
function getMarker(letter) {
    return $('mtgt_'+letter+'.1000');
}
```

Sort of ad-hoc-y, but I'm still not sure what you're getting at.