# How to add Class to marker in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I have created a dynamic list of markers in a map and created a dynamic image URL for an icon.
Now I want to set image to be small on a mobile device so I want to give custom class to my marker. Is it possible?

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,        
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(MY LAT,-MY LONG),
    zoomControl: true,

     var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(MY LAT,-MY LONG);
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng1,
            map: map,
            icon: 'www.example.com/folder/1.png'
        });
```

So above is my logic code now I want to add a class to the marker icon. So I can manage markers on any device as well as play with jQuery using a class.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006511/add-html-class-id-to-google-maps-marker-api-v3)

Comment: Why don't you create 2 images and break the logic in the map code?

Comment: already i have 10+ images. i used loop and change image name. but problem is i want to display  that image to be small if i see it in mobile.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically markers are not single HTML-elements, there also isn't any API-based access to the HTML-elements.

There are workarounds to access the `<img/>`-elements(based on the img-src), but this wouldn't help you much, because you also must modify the clickable area, which will be defined in another pane.

You better forget the CSS-based attempt and use the API-way to scale the markers by setting the `scaledSize`-property of the marker.

Simple demo:

```js
//just for demonstration, implement your own mobile-detection here
window.isMobile = confirm('are you using a mobile device?');


function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png',
      scaledSize: (window.isMobile) 
                    ? new google.maps.Size(20, 34) 
                    : new google.maps.Size(40, 68)

    }
  })
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```